# Updating OS X 10.6 install screen stuck

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I just re-installed Mac OS X 10.6 on my MacBook Pro (2008 ed) using the original DVD. I then selected update software to bring it up to 10.6.8. The software downloaded and then I received the message to restart in order to install the software.

I restarted and have the installation screen showing. Not sure what that screen is called but it is the one that looks like the galaxy.

Nothing is happening—it seems stuck there. I have no window telling me to continue, or agree or install, as is the usual order of things. I have tried this twice; i.e. have used the power button to shut down because the computer does not respond to anything else when that screen is on. Then I re-did update software, receive the message that the software has already downloaded, told to restart in order to install, and the same thing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: How long have you waited? Just try to leave it overnight.

Comment: Did you go through Software Update? Might be worth downloading the Combo Update: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399?locale=en_GB

Comment: Is it *still* stuck?

Answer (score 1):

If you reinstalled without erasing the disk, you might have something incompatible from your previous system. Try to restart holding the SHIFT key. This brings you into safe mode, where only apple components are loaded. The system might react slow, but should let you apply the update. (Would also prefer the combo update, as mentioned by 'forquare'.)

Answer (score -1):

Click into 'show details' before you start the download, then untick all the itunes updates and start the download. It should work fine then. Hope that helps.